# Adding scrolling to a top/down shooter

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

I am trying to create a top down shoot in the vein of "Raiden 2" and I am having trouble adding a scrolling map. When I add a rectangular map and incorporate a camera class, the camera doesn't place the ship at the bottom of the map, allow the ship to fly to the lower half of the map, or keep the ship in the middle of the screen.

I want the ship to be placed at the bottom of the map and the camera to slowly scroll upwards keeping the ship in the same place.

Here is a simplified version of the game with a ship that you can control around the screen:

```
import sys, pygame, os, math

# Force static position of screen
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

# Constants
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (70, 70, 70)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

WIN_W = 500
WIN_H = 800

SHIP_WIDTH = WIN_W/15
SHIP_HEIGHT = WIN_H/15


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class Ship(Entity):
    def __init__(self, container):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 5
        self.image = pygame.Surface((SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = container.centerx
        self.rect.y = container.centery

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.centery -= self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.centery += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.centerx += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.speed

        # Ship Movement Boundaries
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
        if self.rect.y > WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.y = WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        if self.rect.x > WIN_W - SHIP_WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = WIN_W - SHIP_WIDTH


def main():
    # Initialize Everything
    pygame.init()
    fps = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    play = True
    pygame.display.set_caption('Raiden')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H), pygame.SRCALPHA)

    # Create Groups
    shipGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # Create Game Objects
    ship = Ship(pygame.rect.Rect(0, 0, WIN_W, WIN_H))

    # Add Game Objects to Groups
    shipGroup.add(ship)

    # Gameplay
    while play:
        # Checks if window exit button pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        # Update
        ship.update()


        # Print Background/Sprites
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        shipGroup.draw(screen)

        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

This is what happens when I add a rectangular map with a camera class, notice that the map has 5 'platforms' on the right side, however the game doesn't allow you to travel to the lower half of the map.

```
import sys, pygame, os, math

# Force static position of screen
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

# Constants
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (70, 70, 70)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

WIN_W = 500
WIN_H = 800

SHIP_WIDTH = WIN_W/15
SHIP_HEIGHT = WIN_H/15


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class Ship(Entity):
    def __init__(self, container):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 5
        self.image = pygame.Surface((SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = container.centerx
        self.rect.y = container.centery

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.centery -= self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.centery += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.centerx += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.speed

        # Ship Movement Boundaries
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
        if self.rect.y > WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.y = WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        if self.rect.x > WIN_W - SHIP_WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = WIN_W - SHIP_WIDTH

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)


def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return pygame.Rect(-l+WIN_W/2, -t+WIN_H/2, w, h)


def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+WIN_W/2, -t+WIN_H/2, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_W), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_H), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return pygame.Rect(l, t, w, h)


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(GRAY)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

def main():
    # Initialize Everything
    pygame.init()
    fps = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    play = True
    pygame.display.set_caption('Raiden')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H), pygame.SRCALPHA)

    # Create Groups
    shipGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
    backgroundGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # Load Level
    platforms = []
    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]
    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                backgroundGroup.add(p)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    total_level_width = len(level[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level)*32

    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)


    # Create Game Objects
    ship = Ship(pygame.rect.Rect(0, 0, WIN_W, WIN_H))

    # Add Game Objects to Groups
    shipGroup.add(ship)


    # Gameplay
    while play:
        # Checks if window exit button pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
        camera.update(ship)
        # Update
        ship.update()

        # Print Background/Sprites
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        for e in backgroundGroup:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        shipGroup.draw(screen)

        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrolling camera works by calculating a new position for the sprites. For your background tiles, you use `screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))`, which would work, but for the ship, you simply call `shipGroup.draw(screen)`.

But the `shipGroup` does not know about the camera, and thus will always blit the ship sprite at the absolute position, not the relative one the camera class would calculate.

We can fix this by creating a sprite group that can handle the camera, like:

```
class CameraGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self, camera):
        pygame.sprite.Group.__init__(self)
        self.camera = camera

    def draw(self, surface):
        sprites = self.sprites()
        surface_blit = surface.blit
        for spr in sprites:
            self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, self.camera.apply(spr))
        self.lostsprites = []
```

and to use it:

```
...
total_level_width = len(level[0])*32
total_level_height = len(level)*32

# Create Groups
camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
shipGroup = CameraGroup(camera)
backgroundGroup = CameraGroup(camera)

# build the level
for row in level:
   ...
...
```

and in your main loop:

```
while play:
    # Checks if window exit button pressed
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         ...

    camera.update(ship)
    # Update
    ship.update()

    # Print Background/Sprites
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    backgroundGroup.draw(screen)
    shipGroup.draw(screen)

    # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
    ...
```

Now the scrolling will work. Another issue is this check in your `Ship` class:

```
    if self.rect.y > WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT:
        self.rect.y = WIN_H - SHIP_HEIGHT
```

This will prevent the ship from moving further down than `WIN_H`, but your level is actually bigger than the screen height.

To fix this, we create a `Rect` that describes the entire level, and pass it to the `Ship` class:

```
total_rect = pygame.rect.Rect(0, 0, total_level_width, total_level_height)

ship = Ship(total_rect)
```

and then we use it in the `Ship` class to start at the bottom of the level, and we use `clamp_ip` to ensure the ship can't leave the screen:

```
class Ship(Entity):
    def __init__(self, container):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 5
        self.image = pygame.Surface((SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = container.centerx
        self.rect.y = container.bottom - self.rect.height * 2
        self.container = container

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.centery -= self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.centery += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.centerx += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.speed

        self.rect.clamp_ip(self.container)
```

Also, since your level width is 16 blocks * 32 pixel, `WIN_W` should be

```
WIN_W = 16*32
```

if you only want vertical scrolling, and not horizontal scrolling also.

Here's the full code:

```
import sys, pygame, os, math

# Force static position of screen
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

# Constants
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (70, 70, 70)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

WIN_W = 16*32
WIN_H = 800

SHIP_WIDTH = WIN_W/15
SHIP_HEIGHT = WIN_H/15


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class Ship(Entity):
    def __init__(self, container):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 5
        self.image = pygame.Surface((SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = container.centerx
        self.rect.y = container.bottom - self.rect.height * 2
        self.container = container

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.centery -= self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.centery += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.centerx += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.speed

        self.rect.clamp_ip(self.container)

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)


def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return pygame.Rect(-l+WIN_W/2, -t+WIN_H/2, w, h)


def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+WIN_W/2, -t+WIN_H/2, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_W), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_H), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return pygame.Rect(l, t, w, h)

class CameraGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self, camera):
        pygame.sprite.Group.__init__(self)
        self.camera = camera

    def draw(self, surface):
        sprites = self.sprites()
        surface_blit = surface.blit
        for spr in sprites:
            self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, self.camera.apply(spr))
        self.lostsprites = []

class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(GRAY)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

def main():
    # Initialize Everything
    pygame.init()
    fps = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    play = True
    pygame.display.set_caption('Raiden')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H), pygame.SRCALPHA)

    # Load Level
    platforms = []
    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P           PPPP",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPP           P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "P              P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

    total_level_width = len(level[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level)*32
    total_rect = pygame.rect.Rect(0, 0, total_level_width, total_level_height)

    # Create Groups
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    shipGroup = CameraGroup(camera)
    backgroundGroup = CameraGroup(camera)

    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                backgroundGroup.add(p)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    # Create Game Objects
    ship = Ship(total_rect)

    # Add Game Objects to Groups
    shipGroup.add(ship)

    # Gameplay
    while play:
        # Checks if window exit button pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        camera.update(ship)
        # Update
        ship.update()

        # Print Background/Sprites
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        backgroundGroup.draw(screen)
        shipGroup.draw(screen)

        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```